# finite support definition of abelian group

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I met this definition of **finite support** in Prof. Jean Gallier's book "Algebra, Topology, Differential Calculus, and Optimization Theory For CS and ML" (in Page 67)

> If $A$ is an abelian group with identity $0$, we say that a family $(a_i)_{i \in I}$ has finite support if $a_t=0$ for all $i \in I-J$, where $J$ is a finite subset of $I$ (the support of the family).

i don't quite understand two things:

1. what does this definition talk about? what does it mean?
2. what is **finite support**, or the concept of **support** used for? does this have any relation with **Support Vector Machine**

Any help would be great~

Comment: I'm sure it has nothing to do with "Support Vector Machine" (whatever that is).

Answer (score 2):

In general, the support of a function, sequence, etc. is the "smallest set" on which it is nonzero. (I put "smallest set" in quotes only because in some contexts the definition of support requires some property, such as being a closed set.)

In this apparently discrete context, the support $J$ will literally be the set $\{i\in I\colon a_i\ne0\}$, and the family has finite support if this set $J$ is finite.

Comment: could you give a specific example?

Comment: Consider the sequence $$x = \{x_1,x_2,\dots\} = \{4,0,3,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,\dots\}.$$ The support of $x$ is $$\{n\colon x_n\ne0\}=\{1,3,5,7\}.$$